# Why we can set variations for the metric and its derivatives to zero at infinity?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, boundary-terms

This question is the continuation of the Phys.SE post [Einstein action and the second derivatives](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90200/). I still don't understand why eq. $(1)$ therein may be set to zero. This refers to the zero value variations of metric and its derivatives on the infinitely far surface. But why we can assume that? To which principle does it refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Einstein-Hilbert action of general relativity, to make the variational principle fully rigorous, must be supplemented by a boundary term,
$$S = \frac{1}{8\pi G} \int_{\partial M} d^3 x \sqrt{-h} \, K$$

where $h_{\mu \nu}$ is the first fundamental form of a submanifold which we take to be $\partial M$, the boundary of the spacetime manifold. The cuvature $K$ is the trace of the extrinsic curvature. So your concerns are justified, strictly speaking, one should include a boundary term, unless the manifold has no boundary.

(The boundary term was first derived by Gibbons, Hawking and York. For additional information, I highly recommend the gravitational physics lectures online from the Perimeter Institute by Professor Ruth Gregory - her lectures are excellent.)